Type error on custom API route in Next.js 15 when deploying to Netlify or running `npm run build`
My application works fine on npm run dev.
However, when deploying to Netlify or running npm run build locally i get this error:
app/api/projects/[projectId]/activity/route.ts
Type error: Route "app/api/projects/[projectId]/activity/route.ts" has an invalid "GET" export:
  Type "{ params: Record<string, string>; }" is not a valid type for the function's second argument.

The app/api/projects/[projectId]/activity/route.ts files includes the following:
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { supabase } from '@/lib/supabase';

export async function GET(
  request: NextRequest,
  { params }: { params: Record<string, string> }
) {
  try {
    const projectId = params.projectId;

    const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from('activity_log')
      .select('*')
      .eq('project_id', projectId)
      .order('timestamp', { ascending: false });

    if (error) throw error;

    return NextResponse.json({ activities: data });
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Failed to fetch activity log' }, { status: 500 });
  }
}

This is running NextJS 15. Somewhat of a noob so happy to provide any further environment or codebase data.
I have tried every possible Claude fix along with rewriting the api routes from scratch. I continue to receive the same Type errors.

I was struggling with the same thing and was able to bypass it by disabling the linting for just that line:
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
export async function GET(request: Request, context: { params: any }) {
    const { artistId } = context.params;
    // Rest of your code...
}

I don't think this is a good solution but it gets the build done.

Instead of { params }: { params: Record<string, string> } you can try:
 { params }: { params: string }.

In Next 15 params returns a Promise. So you would need to adjust your code a bit, and wrap your existing code with Promise<> so typescript recognizes that it returns a promise.
Example:
{ params: Promise<Record<string, string>> }

This should pass the type check.
Also, don't forget to await the params!
const { projectId } = await params;

See the docs here for reference.
